# How to make sprites come down from top of screen?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm making a simple iOS game where the goal is to fire arrows from a bow at the bottom of the screen to destroy monsters coming from the top of the screen. I have this bit of code, but it only makes monsters spawn and move left from the right side of the screen. Here's the code:

```
- (void) spawnMonster
{
    SKSpriteNode *monster = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: @"Monster"];
    monster.xScale = 0.5;
    monster.yScale = 0.5;

    int minY = monster.size.height / 2;
    int maxY = self.frame.size.height - monster.size.height / 2;
    int rangeY = maxY - minY;
    int actualY = (arc4random() % rangeY) + minY;

    monster.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + monster.size.width / 2, actualY);
    [self addChild: monster];

    int minDuration = 2.0;
    int maxDuration = 4.0;
    int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
    int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

    SKAction *actionMove = [SKAction moveTo: CGPointMake(-monster.size.width / 2, actualY) duration: actualDuration];
    SKAction *actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    [monster runAction: [SKAction sequence: @[actionMove, actionMoveDone]]];
}
```

Suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You have start location and you have a target location that is defined in your definition of `actionMove`. Take a moment to think about how you can utilize those two aspects to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want objects falling from the top then you should set the arc4random function to the monster sprite's X and not Y. The Y should always be the top of your view. Remember x is the left/right axis and y is the up/down axis.